# SQL query to get column of the next row to be of column of a row and the second row of the column to the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a SQL query to get column of the next row to be of column of a row. the test example is as follows

[image]

I want to get SQL query to get result as follow:

[image]

Comment: Join to itself referring to ID = PreviousId - 1.  What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `LEAD` provided the version you are on supports it.

```
select customer,orderdate,item,
lead(orderdate,1) over(partition by customer order by date) as second_date,
lead(item,1) over(partition by customer order by date) as second_item,
lead(orderdate,2) over(partition by customer order by date) as third_date,
lead(item,2) over(partition by customer order by date) as third_item
from tbl
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps me partially.

Comment: you should post another question..instead of changing the question after accepting an answer.

Comment: This forum is only allowing me to post one question per day. Just wondering if the other scenario that I posted can be possible?